# Current screen resolution in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

How can I get the current screen resolution of the screen where my form is?

I've already tried with primaryScreen but it does not work all times.

```
this.Size = new Size(Math.Min(width + 19, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width), Math.Min(height + dgvActualizar.ColumnHeadersHeight + 40, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height));
```

Comment: How it does not work? What is the problem when it does not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `FromControl` method:

```
Screen screenFormIsOn = Screen.FromControl(this);
var width = screenFormIsOn.WorkingArea.Width;
var height = screenFormIsOn.WorkingArea.Height;
```

`Screen.FromControl` should return the screen in which your form is loaded on.

Answer (score 3):

See the following documentation for Screen class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8xzhd15.aspx

```
Screen current = Screen.FromControl(this);
Rectangle area = current.WorkingArea;
```

You can then get

```
area.Width
```

and

```
area.Height.
```

Comment: Can the person who downvoted my answer tell me how I can edit/revise my answer? Thanks.

Comment: I am not the person who downvoted, but you could type the variable names in the same lines using \`area.Width\`

Comment: Right. I will make those changes.